# How to determine which domain a mobile client belongs to

Tags: c#, api, xamarin

I have the following set up for a web application

User X (browser) --> www.companyX.com/api/somemethod()--> Database X

user Y (browser)--> www.companyY.com/api/somemethod()--> Database Y

On the web application, the web config file contains the baseURI

so for company X = www.companyX.com and for Y =  www.companyY.com

from this we can determine the relevant base URI.

Now i am trying to write a xamarin android app for this, when the app is downloaded by a user, what is the best way, or how can i go about to determine which company this user belongs to, and therefor determine and save the baseURI  to local storage?.

one of the idea was, during the logon screen, user enters his email and password, and then i iterate though all existing Logon end points

www.companyX.com/api/Logon()

www.companyY.com/api/Logon()

www.companyZ.com/api/Logon()

which in turn will potentially hit all the databases to find that email address and then when it finds it, we know which company user belongs to and store the base URI in local storage.

But i dont like this approach, was wondering if there is better way to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: To clarify your attempting to get a one app fits all kind of thing? Does the data that is pulled down affect anything within the app that is populated dynamically that is 'non-standard' between the companies?

Comment: Just to clarify Each company have their own db. company x has an employee table so does company y. Tables are identical, just the data in them will be specific for each company.  In a web application we have a app config web config to store the base uri which we use as a prefix to an end point. But in a mobile app when a user downloads it for the first time I need away to determine which company this user belongs to so that I can store the base uri. And ensure this users calls the appropriate api.

Comment: Some multi-tenant apps/platforms ask for a company/server code besides the common user and password informations.

Comment: Ideally you don't want to loop through each DB for the users details because you're increasing the return times. It might be an idea to provide a simple yet functional drop down box, so that the user can select their company from a list that you can pre-populate or populate dynamically from a web service call etc.

Comment: Are these company email addresses? ( for example user@companyx.com or anotheruser@companyy.com )  I would think you could have a central service to lookup the service url based on the email domain

Comment: Drop-down was proposed where the user can select their company from a list. But the powers be decided not to expose other company details to user. Unfortunately the email addresses do not include the company domain, users can have personal email address like Hotmail gmail etc. I am thinking about the following solution.. central service--central db. The db has a table with mobile code and company base uri. Users enters the code which uses central service api gets the company base uri. Unless any other suggestions.